# How to reduce database connection by making one PDO instance for your entire project

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class I have made that looks like this:

```
class Database 
{
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_NAME = "office";
    const DB_USERNAME = "root";
    const DB_PASSWORD = "root";
    public $connection;

    function Database()
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".Database::DB_HOST.";dbname=".Database::DB_NAME, Database::DB_USERNAME, Database::DB_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

I wanna use a single instance for the database using `$database = new Database();`

My problem is **functions** not finding it.

I rather not use `GLOBAL $database` nor use `$_SESSION` to solve it.

Any other ways I've missed?

Comment: Do you mean a singleton class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776788/best-practice-on-php-singleton-classes

Comment: @xd6_, Nope don't use a singleton , go for dependency injection instead.

Comment: No, I'm actually looking for a way to use the instance in functions without having to globalize it in every function I make, nor making a new instance in every function.

Comment: @Shankar is right, but DI is a bit more involved than a singleton. There's a balance between doing it perfectly and understanding everything, of course.

Comment: Jacob, a singleton will do that for you - a static variable in a function or static method will maintain one instance without interfering with globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is making a Singleton class
BUT Because PDO uses a connection from a pool the construction of a new PDO is very very ligthweight and i think it's just a good practice just to reconstruct a new PDO (or Database)

```
class Database {

    private static $instance = null;

    private __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
      if(self::$instance === null) {
         self::$instance = new Database();
      }
      return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

You can reach the object by using

```
$database = Database::getInstance(); //this wil not construct a new Database object
```

Still i really discourage the approach because constructing a new PDO object is so leightweight you won't even notice the difference

More information at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Just an example of releasing PDO 
See: [How to close a PDO handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067980/how-to-close-a-pdo-handle)

```
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
   //This happens somewhere in the loop
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(
                     PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                 ));
   //use $pdo
   unset($pdo); //This will release your connection and returns it to the pool
}
```

Comment: Will functions OUTSIDE this class be able to reach this instance?

Comment: @JacobCohen yes  Database::getInstance() will return the instance

Comment: Even though it is lightweight, when you have 100k people entering your system simultaneously, and a page have a function that uses connection in a loop, the amount of connection will very fast be reached.
It seems like singleton is a perfect solution to reduce that, even though I still need to write getInstance for each function, which I was trying to avoid... It basically just like globalizing the database instance on each function.

Comment: @JacobCohen that's why you can construct a PDO before the looping, and even when you construct a PDO in a loop, you can release the object when you are done the connection will be returned to the pool. but you can use the singleton approach

Comment: @JacobCohen I added the example for in a loop ;) bit simple but i'l think you get it

Comment: That's what Ive been doing so far... Are you telling me I shouldn't change anything? :P

Comment: With the unset? i could be wrong tho =) I'm not programming that much in php anymore

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Check the persistent connections ;)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but this is overkill.

I want a different connection everytime someone access a certain page. However I do not want it to open a new one every FUNCTION, coz you may call a function many times in one script.

Still your first solution fits better to my needs.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a constructor here

```
class Database 
    {
        public $conn;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $DB_HOST = '';
            $DB_NAME = '';
            $DB_USERNAME = '';
            $DB_PASSWORD = '';
            $this->conn= new PDO("mysql:host=".$DB_HOST.";dbname=".$DB_NAME, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @downvoter please explain?

Comment: Using the class name as a function (without public before it) is a constructor.

Comment: @Jacob, yes, although that approach is no longer recommended. Always use `__construct()` for your constructors, and always declare their access level too.

Comment: @JacobCohen As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor

Comment: I dont use no namespaces in my project, is there a threat still?

Comment: Not really but it is bad practice to use the class name as constructor like you do in your example.

Comment: I guess im too used to C#..

Comment: Btw Daan I wasnt the downvoter, I just assumed this is why he down voted.